# Sencha Touch/ExtJS: Tiled scroll view (like CATiledLayer)

Tags: html, cordova, sencha-touch-2, tile, catiledlayer

I'm looking for something like `CATiledLayer` (on iOS), but for use in PhoneGap/Sencha Touch 2.

The idea is to "stream" a very large image from a server in form of tiles - very much like Google Maps does the job.

It should support touch gestures on mobile devices so a user can pinch zoom and scroll.

Unfortunately I couldn't find something - so a few pointers are highly appreciated.

---

## Update:

In the meanwhile I took a look at [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/), which seems to what I want and manages multiple layers of zooming and such. Unfortunately it is hooked too much into Geospartial data and there is no way to disable projections to make it work like a basic image viewer.

I also found [GSV](http://mike.teczno.com/giant/pan/) (Big Ass Image Viewer) - unfortunately I doesn't support touch gestures and generally seems to be abandoned.

To me it's just weird that nobody really had the need for something like this and I try to prevent "re-inventing the wheel" as much as I can. But right now it does not look like there are any non-geodata/map related solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen anything like this done using Sencha Touch 2, though I'm going to assume that putting something like this together wouldn't require much.

It would basically be your custom component (which would be scrollable). Inside that component you would insert 1 child which would be the size of your image (lets say; 15000px x 15000px) so it overflows. You would then listen to the scroll event on the parent container and when it gets to a certain x/y state, update the child item with that section of the image.

I'm not sure what the best solution for the child's HTML would be. Perhaps a bunch of divs, but I'm thinking `<canvas>` would be best for images.